# Does $\text{rank}(AB) = \text{rank}(BA) = r$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

$A$ and $B$ are both $n \times n$ matrices. $A$ has rank $r$ and $B$ has rank $n$ (invertible).

My question is: Does $\text{rank}(AB) = \text{rank}(BA) = r$ for any $A$?

Comment: Yes, that is true.  Probably you can show this yourself with a result such as row rank of $A$ equals column rank of $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $B$ is invertible, $rank(AB)=rank(A)=r$ for any such $A$. It follows from the fact that $rank(AB) \le \min\{rank(A),rank(B)\}$

Observe that $Ker(B) \subset Ker(AB)$ and $Range AB \subset RangeA$. Can you use Rank-Nullity Theorem to conclude from here ??

Comment: I'm relatively new to linear algebra, may I  ask why rank(AB)≤min{rank(A),rank(B)} ? Is it a theorem?

Comment: @TonyTarng See now.

Comment: So is this correct: if I know that Range(AB) and Range(A) are equal, then this implies that the rank (AB) = rank(A) = r? Also, how do I know that the Range(AB) and Range(A) are equal in this case? I understand why Ker(B) is same as Ker(AB). (Sorry if this is a dumb question)

Comment: @TonyTarng I am not saying they are same. I am saying one is contained in the other

Comment: This answer that "it follows from the fact that $rank(AB) \le \min\{rank(A),rank(B)\}$" is at best incomplete.  Equality does not follow from the inequality that $rank(AB) \le rank(A)$.

Comment: @hardmath you have to use it twice by setting $C=AB$ and since $B$ is invertible, $CB^{-1}=A$ and using the inequality on these two you will have Rank$C \le $Rank$A$ and Rank$A \le $ Rank$C$

Comment: Thanks.  These various clarifications deserve to be edited into the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

For any matrix $A$, the rank of $A$ is equal to $r$ **iff** there exists invertible matrices $U, V$ such that
$$A=UE^{(r)}V,$$ where $E^{(r)}_{i,i}=1$ for $1\le i\le r$ and zero others. So for any invertible matrix $B$ this criteria works with matrices $U, VB$ or $BU, V$

Comment: This is not a usual definition of **rank**, and showing its equivalence with [any of those](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Main_definitions) seems at least as involved as showing what the Question here asks (that multiplication by an invertible matrix on either side does not change the rank of a matrix).  So I regard this as essentially burying the requested result in an alternative definition.